# Do where statements get evaluated multiple times?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, if I write something like

```hs
foo a = b + c
  where 
    n = length a
    b = n + 2
    c = n * 2
```

Does `n` get evaluated multiple times?

Comment: Normally you refer to the same node, hence `n` will be evaluated once. So if `b` is first evaluated, then `c` will use the result of `n`. Note however that if you do not need `foo a`, `n` does not get evaluated at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That should have been an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell the language makes no promises.

The current implementation of GHC will not produce code that evaluates `length a` multiple times.

(But beware: this case is somewhat special in that `n`'s type is fully monomorphic. Class-polymorphic bindings may be evaluated repeatedly; you can read more about this on the [monomorphism restriction wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction).)